# fscanf dynamic array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, malloc, scanf

So, my big homework is to make a who wants to be millionare game in C, but I have a little problem. I have a csv file with 5000 rows of datas like these:

...

4;How old I am?;22;dog;yellow;who knows;A;PERSONAL

2;Where is Utrecht?;England;Nietherland;France;Sweden;B;GEOLOGY

15;...

...

I always have to scan one question of the 5000, always needs to be more difficulty then the previous (easy, we have 15 levels of difficulties and 15 question), and needs to be printed on the screen (so I need the question, the answers and the others separately (GEOLOGY not needed)). But the problem: I have to use malloc always! How could be possible to know how long the string will be?

I'm here:

```
    srand(time(NULL));
    int num=1;
    char* onerow=(char*) malloc(num*sizeof(char));
    int row=rand()%1000;
    char c;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("proba.txt", "r");

    for (int i=0; i<=row-1; i++) {
        if(i!=row-1) {          //not the row we need, jump over it
            while(c!='\n')
                c=fgetc(fp);
        }
        if(i==row-1) {
            for(int j=0; onerow[j]!='\n'; j++) {    //this is what we need
                onerow[j]=fgetc(fp);
                onerow = (char *) realloc(onerow, ++num*sizeof(char));
            }
        }
    }
    onerow[num]='\0';
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%s\n", onerow);
    free(onerow);
}
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I tried to count all the characters in one whole row (to take apart the datas later) if the first letter was what i needed (the difficulty). But then I couldn't scan the row with fgets, only the next row.

Comment: well try to show code for the first line parsing, then we'll probably be able to help you with it.

Comment: I am learning programming at the university only for 2 months, I simply can't make a code which can do this, however i was working on it for the last 3 days.

Comment: `int main(void) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    char onerow[255];
    int row=rand()%1000;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("proba.txt", "r");

    for (i=0; i<=row-1; i++) {
        fgets(onerow, 255, (FILE*)fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%s\n", onerow);
}`

Comment: @GergoMiklos: No, edit it into the question.

Comment: After reading rows with `for (int i=0; i < row; i++) {` and throwing them away, get the next line and print that.  Suggest `fgets(onerow, sizeof onerow, fp);`

Comment: Could scan with `if (sscanf(onerow, "%99[;];%99[;];%99[;];%99[;];%99[;];%99[;];%99[;];%99[;]", 8 x 100 char arrays...) == 8)` --> O happy day.

Comment: OP's posted code is maybe 5% of the needed code for the task.  A good start yet far more to be written.  Suggest coding a portion of the HW and then posting a question on a small part - like how to read a line?  Next steps, read a file,  select 1st question, select next question, etc.

Comment: "How could be possible to know how long the string will be?"  Robust code allows for a large generous, yet fixed upper bound.  Alternatively go through the file twice and find the longest line, then rescan.  Good luck.

Comment: I made a new code, which need to be good, with malloc. But it is not working. The onerow string contains the second row, always (not the random row), and it also contains the next row's first three character for plus. Can you help me guys?

Comment: Just duplicate the pointer, use one to count and the other to read

Answer (score 2):

Gergo, you are making things way harder on yourself than they need to be. First, surely you know (or can determine) what the maximum length of a line in `proba.txt` is. There is absolutely no need to dynamically allocate anything. Simply declare `onerow` as a character array sufficiently large to hold a row of data (including the `'\n'` and *nul-terminating* character, and read/discard `row - 1` rows and then make a final call to `fgets` to read the row you are interested in.

Also, don't hardcode filenames or use other *magic numbers* in your code. If you need constants, then `#define` them up top so you have a single convenient location to make changes as required. For example, to set the *max row length* and filename, you can use something like the following:

```
#define MAXR 512            /* max chars per line (adjust as required */
#define FNAME "proba.txt"   /* filename */
...
```

Next all arrays and counting in C is `zero` based. While you can count from any number you like, keeping things consistent helps keep things straight in your mind. As such, `num` starts at `0` as `row = rand() % 1000;` returns values from `0-999`. Making those changes, your declarations could look like the following:

```
srand(time(NULL));          /* seed the random number generator */

int num = 0,                /* counter variable */
    row = rand() % 1000;    /* row to read */
size_t len = 0;             /* length of row */
char onerow[MAXR] = "", c;
FILE *fp = fopen (FNAME, "r");
```

**Note:** you must *validate* that your file is actually open for reading, otherwise you will invoke *Undefined Behavior* attempting to read from a non-open file-stream, e.g. \

```
if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
    fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'\n", FNAME);
    return 1
}
```

As mentioned above, once the file is open, all you need to do is read and discard `row-1` lines and then read a final time to read the `row`<sup>th</sup> line into `onerow` and then close the file, e.g.

```
while (num++ < row)             /* read/discard row - 1 lines */
    fgets (onerow, MAXR, fp);
fgets (onerow, MAXR, fp);       /* read row line */
fclose (fp);                    /* close file */
```

Since we use `fgets` (a *line-oriented* input function), we must *validate* the final character in `onerow` is the `'\n'` to verify that a complete line was read. After confirming the last char is the `'\n'` char, we simply remove it by overwriting with the *nul-terminating* character so we don't have a `'\n'` dangling off the end of the string. Simply get the length, check, and overwrite:

```
len = strlen (onerow);          /* get onerow length */
if (onerow[len - 1] == '\n')    /* validate last char is '\n' */
    onerow[--len] = 0;          /* overwrite with nul-character */
else {
    fprintf (stderr, "error: line '%d' exceeds '%d' chars.\n",
            num, MAXR);
    return 1;
}
```

If you have made it this far, you have the line you want in `onerow` and all that is left is to:

```
printf ("%s\n", onerow);
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.